# dynamically set initialization value based on condition inside loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have initially set a `$rowID` value on initialising the loop through result-set for the first time.

On given condition, the value for `$rowID` needs to be re-set to some other value, so that next loop run will use that value.

Here's my code:

```
$col = 'A';
$last_grid_row = 0; /* this is what I tried */
foreach($records as $key=>$item)
{
    $rowID = 1;
    if($key % 4 == 0):
        $col = 'A';
        $rowID = $last_grid_row; /* this is what I tried */
    endif;
    $rowID = $rowID; /* this is what I tried */

    /* cell value assigning */
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowID, $item['date']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setWidth(40);

    $menu_items = unserialize($item['lunch_items']);

    foreach($menu_items as $list):
        $last_grid_row = $rowID++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowID, $list);
    endforeach;
    $col++;    
}
```

Here's what I try to achieve in excel:

```
A     |  B     |  C     |  D
-------------------------------
2018  |  2019  |  2020  |  2021
ram   |  sam   |  dam   |  ham
bam   |  cam   |  lam   |  kam
jam   |  nam   |  pam   |  nam   <- last_row 

2022  |  2023  |  2024  |  2025
ram   |  sam   |  dam   |  ham
bam   |  cam   |  lam   |  kam
jam   |  nam   |  pam   |  nam
```

After every fourth column record, I want to move next record to first column 'A' and initialize the row value `rowID` to value of `last_row` from the previous grid.

So that next grid, the fifth record can start from column 'A' again, and next level row.

I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work.

I use array chunk to only loop the years four at the time and reset column at each iteration.
Then I nest another loop that outputs the four sub arrays of years.

```
$rowoffset =0;
Foreach(array_chunk($records,4) as $items){
    $col =1;
    Foreach($items as $rowID => $val){
        $row = $rowID+1+$rowoffset;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$row, $item['date']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setWidth(40);
    }
    $rowoffset = $rowID +3;
    $col++;
}
```

This is slightly simplified, but it's more to show the logic than be a perfect answer.
An example that only echos the rows it's printing on

https://3v4l.org/mge06